# How to add a row to a pandas DataFrame without flattening the MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have trouble with adding a single row to a MultiIndexed DataFrame in an efficient way. By adding the row, the MultiIndex is flattened to a simple Index of Tuples. Strangely this is not a problem for MultiIndexed columns.

System info:

```
Python 3.6.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar 22 2017, 19:25:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.19.2'
```

Example data: A DataFrame with both MultiIndex rows and columns

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'foo'], ['one', 'two']],
                      labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
                      names=['row_0', 'row_1'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['dull', 'shiny'], ['a', 'b']],
                      labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
                      names=['col_0', 'col_1'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((4,4)),columns=columns, index=index)

print(df)

    col_0       dull      shiny     
col_1          a    b     a    b
row_0 row_1                     
bar   one    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
      two    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
foo   one    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
      two    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
```

It's no problem to add an additional column to the DataFrame:

```
df['last_col'] = 42 #define a new column and assign a value

print(df)

col_0       dull      shiny      last_col
col_1          a    b     a    b         
row_0 row_1                              
bar   one    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0       42
      two    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0       42
foo   one    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0       42
      two    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0       42
```

However, if i do the same for adding a row (by using loc), the MultiIndex is flattened to a
simple Index of Tuples:

```
df.loc['last_row'] = 43  #define a new row and assign a value

print(df)

col_0       dull       shiny       last_col
col_1          a     b     a     b         
(bar, one)   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0       42
(bar, two)   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0       42
(foo, one)   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0       42
(foo, two)   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0       42
last_row    43.0  43.0  43.0  43.0       43
```

Does anyone has an idea how to add a row without flattening the index in a both simple and efficient way? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17024

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need tuple with define both values of `MultiIndex`:

```
df.loc[('last_row', 'a'), :] = 43
print(df)
col_0           dull       shiny      
col_1              a     b     a     b
row_0    row_1                        
bar      one     1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
         two     1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
foo      one     1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
         two     1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
last_row a      43.0  43.0  43.0  43.0
```

For column it works similar:

```
df[('last_col', 'a')] = 43
print(df)
col_0       dull      shiny      last_col
col_1          a    b     a    b        a
row_0 row_1                              
bar   one    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0       43
      two    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0       43
foo   one    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0       43
      two    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0       43
```

EDIT:

It seems you need define columns names, if need all use `:`:

```
df.loc['last_row',:] = 43
print(df)
col_0           dull       shiny      
col_1              a     b     a     b
row_0    row_1                        
bar      one     1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
         two     1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
foo      one     1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
         two     1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
last_row        43.0  43.0  43.0  43.0
```

If level is not defined is added empty string:

```
print(df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'foo', 'last_row'], ['one', 'two', '']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=['row_0', 'row_1'])
```

```
df.loc['last_row','dull'] = 43
print(df)
col_0           dull       shiny     
col_1              a     b     a    b
row_0    row_1                       
bar      one     1.0   1.0   1.0  1.0
         two     1.0   1.0   1.0  1.0
foo      one     1.0   1.0   1.0  1.0
         two     1.0   1.0   1.0  1.0
last_row        43.0  43.0   NaN  NaN
```

```
df.loc['last_row', ('dull', 'a')] = 43
print(df)
col_0           dull      shiny     
col_1              a    b     a    b
row_0    row_1                      
bar      one     1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
         two     1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
foo      one     1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
         two     1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
last_row        43.0  NaN   NaN  NaN
```